# Buttons not clickable in Hot Towel Template UI

Tags: hottowel

I am using hot towel template in a web application. In the UI, the navigation menu gets rendered from nav.html file. There are other viewmodels and views. In one of the html file, I see that the buttons are not clickable. If I add some **br** tags to move the buttons little downwards in the layout, the buttons becomes clickable.

Comment: Some code would be nice, but its sounds like a div of some sort is overlapping the buttons.

Comment: Yes, it was the div's getting overlapped. You can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a div of some sort is overlapping the buttons.